# Can tourists go higher than 22km? If so, what's the highest they can go?

Tags: air-travel, space

https://www.flyfighterjet.com/edge-of-space-flight ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201224075643/https://www.flyfighterjet.com/edge-of-space-flight)) mentions:

> The MiG-29 Flight is the only fighter aircraft available for Supersonic Flights and Edge of Space Flights. The MiG-29 Fulcrum is also a modern fighter aircraft, belonging to the 4th generation. Given the fact that even European Air Forces still use the much older MiG-21 Fishbed, it is very surprising that tourists can fly in such modern aircraft to an altitude of up to **22km**. **17km is guaranteed**, the altitude reached depends on the weather and the air temperature. The MiG-29 Fulcrum is a Mach 2+ interceptor and a state of the art multirole fighter jet.

Can tourists go higher than 22km? If so, what's the highest they can go?

I'm excluding one-shot, special (and outstandingly pricy) deals such as [the tourist who went to the ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Tito). Also, [sub-orbital spaceflights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-orbital_spaceflight) for space tourists with [Virgin Galactic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Galactic) or others aren't available yet.  Same for more ambitious programs such as [DearMoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DearMoon_project).

Comment: There seem to be some companies planning commercial balloon flights higher than that, e.g. World View and Bloon, about 30km up, but I can't find any that have started operating https://globetrender.com/2020/07/27/high-altitude-balloons-space-tourism-stratosphere/ https://gearjunkie.com/helium-balloon-ride-to-space

Answer (score 3):

It seems Blue Origin is selling tickets now:

https://www.blueorigin.com/new-shepard/reserve-a-seat

Yet I am not sure at what price point "outstandinly pricey" kicks in for you.

I doubt you will find any of this in the 4-digit EUR / USD ranges.